# How to project a 2d point onto a 2d axis in javascript

Tags: javascript, 2d

I have a point defined like `{x:(x value), y: (y value)}`, and I have an axis with a slope and a y intercept. I am trying to project the point onto the line. I have searched 'project point onto line' and looked around for a long time, but i can't find anything that projects a point onto a slope and intercept line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me (a slight change from OP's answer):

```
function project (x, y, slope, yint) {
    var slope2 = -1 / slope;
    var yint2 = y - slope2 * x;
    var nx = (yint2 - yint) / (slope - slope2);
    return {x: nx, y: (slope2 * nx) + yint};
}
```

Comment: What are slope and yint?

Answer (score 1):

The actual answer was simple. I just needed to make a perpendicular line to the other line that touches the point being projected. Then, the projection was just the point of intersection of both of the lines. So I implemented a function in javascript, the parameters being the point's x, the point's y, the line's slope, and the line's y intercept, and it returns the projection as `{x, y}`.

```
function project (x, y, slope, yint) {
    var slope2 = -1 / slope;
    var yint2 = y - slope2 * x;
    var nx = (yint2 - yint) / (slope - slope2);
    return {x: nx, y: (slope2 * nx) + yint}; //thanks to @igobivo for fixing that mistake
}
```

Comment: Hey, I also needed to project point to a line :) However, you made a typo on `return` line.  
Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60758011/2400849) on how to solve it correctly. Also please mark it as a correct solution, thanks!